# Get the current chat history after page refresh

Tags: django, django-channels

I have created a chatbot that can be added in any website and bot will added on all pages of website. Bot is working fine problem is after page refresh or going another page of website, current chat history is lost. How can I show show current chat after page refresh.

I am using django channels for live chat and saving messages in database. When chat start I create a history instance in `Histoy` model, and then save every message in `Conversation` model

This is model to save the chat. This is chat to customer care type app so messages are saved in question/answer form.

```
class ChatHistory(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        ('bot_chat', 'bot_chat'),
        ('user_chat', 'user_chat')
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company_chat')

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='customer_chat')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    chat_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE)
    talker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='user_chat', null=True)
    saved_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trained_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']


class Conversation(models.Model):
    history = models.ForeignKey(ChatHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_history')
    question = models.TextField(null=True)
    answer = models.TextField(null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: *The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Try using cookies and set the expiry of them for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "history" function.

Assuming you can uniquely identify chats between folks, you can publish the last N messages in history for the users on connect, giving a seamless experience controlled from the server side.
This can be complex, but assuming your frontend can re-order it it works great.

Failing that, create an API route for this where a user can query their chat ID and get the last N messages OR the messages with timestamps between the queried period.

All this is easier if you have some kind of time series database for storing the chat, as they are all about fast insertion and time centric query tools. [QuestDB](https://questdb.io) is awesome for this.

This is how we've implemented [Rewind](https://ably.com/documentation/realtime/channels/channel-parameters/rewind) and [History](https://ably.com/documentation/core-features/history) in Ably, and it's used for many large scale chat applications.